# Crystal Reports Parameter display "All" when no value is passed in parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports

So with the reports i've created  they have a set of parameters that when no specific value is past into it, then the report treats it as though you get data for all possible solutions.

> Ex: you have the machine name as a parameter and you do not put in a specific machine name passed into the parameter. Then you get the data returned for all possible machine names in the database. An example of what i am talking about is below.

[image]

However when i put no value into the parameter field no value gets displayed in the report. What i would like is to have it display "All" into the field instead of it coming back as blank.

So my question is how would i go about displaying "All" where the red circle is in the report instead of it coming up as blank when no value is put in for a parameter?

any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you already have the record selection sorted. The four fields in the red circle would be like:

```
if hasvalue({?param}) then
 {?param}
else
 'All';
```

If any of them aren't string values you may need to do:

```
if hasvalue({?param}) then
 cStr({?param})
else
 'All';
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, it works where `isnull()` will not.

Answer (score 2):

Optional parameters require that you use the `hasvalue()` function to check for the cases when there is no value used. So in your case, if you had

`{table.machine_name} = {?machine_name_param}`

you would instead have to use

```
(not(hasvalue({?machine_name_param})) 
or {table.machine_name} = {?machine_name_param})
```

It's basically just like doing a null check like you would for any database field.

Answer (score -1):

Crystal 2008 syntax 
if  Parameter is of type number 
syntax
({?P #}= 0 OR {Command.p} = {?P #} )

if parameter is of type STRING
 SYNTAX
(not HasValue({?D}) OR {Command.d} = {?D})